# Why doesn't "$" work while "(\r|\n)" DOES work in a simple re.search() command with the re.MULTILINE flag set?

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I have stumbled upon a very strange situation, where "$" doesn't work (does not match line-ends) while "(\r|\n)" DOES work, in a simple re.search() command with the re.MULTILINE flag set, and I really wonder why this is?

Here is a short PoC, including its runtime output (when executed on Python 3.7.1):

```
import re

subj = 'row1\r\nContent-Length: 1234\r\nrow3'
test1 = re.search(r'^Content-Length: ([0-9]+)$', subj, re.MULTILINE)
test2 = re.search(r'^Content-Length: ([0-9]+)(\r|\n)', subj, re.MULTILINE)
if test1:
    print('test1 is a match!')
else:
    print('test1 is NOT a match!')
if test2:
    print('test2 is a match!')
else:
    print('test2 is NOT a match!')
```

and here is the output when running this code:

```
test1 is NOT a match!
test2 is a match!
```

As far as I can read in all the docs, the "$" should represent any line-break when using regexps in multiline mode, so why does it refuse to match in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick check of Python RE document shows that only `\n` is treated a newline character; `\r` is not a newline character (although it is a whitespace character). In a multiline match, the "$" seeks a newline character (or, more precisely, the zero-length string to the immediate left of the newline character).

Suggest using this RE:

```
r'^Content-Length: ([0-9]+)\r?$'
```

Comment: Thanks! That really sucks in Python then I think, only supporting "Linux-style" linebreaks, even when executed on Windows, and also not being able to override this behavior, like in PCRE. :-(